# Python Tkinter multiple line input as integer in list

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

I have a problem reading multiple lines of coordinates (like x,y) from a Tkinter Textbox.
The user input will be this:

```
41,3
21,12
68,10
etc.
```

Each Line represents an x,y coordinate. X and Y are seperated by ,.
I need to read this coordinates from the text box and process it in a way that an array forms. Like this:

```
[[41,3],[21,12],[68,10]
```

What i have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *


def get_Data():
   text_from_Box = Text_Entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c').split("\n")
   print text_from_Box


master = Tk()

Label(master, text = "Enter coordinates here:").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

Text_Entry = Text(master, height = 30, width = 30)
Text_Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

Button(master, text = 'Start Calculation', command = get_Data).grid(row = 2,      column = 0, sticky = W)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `split` again at the `','` and convert to `int` (or `float`):

```
def get_Data():
   text_from_Box = Text_Entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c').split("\n")
   numbers = [[int(x) for x in pair.split(",")] for pair in text_from_Box]
   print numbers
```

Comment: you can just do `[map(float,i.split(",")) for i in text_from_box]`

Comment: do you mean: 'numbers = [map(float,i.split(",")) for i in text_from_box]' that didn't work for me

Comment: @Eular Yes, but then I'd need to add a few pages of explanation why this works only in Python 2, but not in Python 3. ;-)

Comment: for python 3 wrap it up with a `list()`